# Filtering text by awk or bash with some specific conditions

Tags: bash, awk, sed, filtering, lines

I have an output (of a well known `btmon` tool) as in example below and I need to parse it and get some info from it in the next way: if UUID is presented in the section `HCI event:` and it equals to `32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3` then take the value of `Address:` and `RSSI:` fields and put them together and make a new line. Also every instance should be put in specific file according to the [hci] number (same line as HCI Event) For example, from every HCI event of hci 0 (meeting the described conditions) it goes to file-hci0.txt, from hci1 to file-hci1.txt and so on for all hciX in a format like this, for hci0(.txt):

> A0:E6:F8:48:38:6F AB
>
> A0:E6:F8:48:87:DA B6

for hci1(.txt):

> A0:E6:F8:48:32:94 C3
>
> A0:E6:F8:48:EF:78 BA

So here is a stream or file I need parse in the described way:

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                       [hci1] 4.746057
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Non connectable undirected - ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x03)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: A0:E6:F8:48:32:94 (Texas Instruments Inc)
        Data length: 31
        Flags: 0x05
          LE Limited Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: not assigned (37984)
          Data: 3248f8e6a000
        128-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3
        RSSI: -61 dBm (0xc3)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                       [hci0] 5.198878
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Non connectable undirected - ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x03)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: A0:E6:F8:48:38:6F (Texas Instruments Inc)
        Data length: 31
        Flags: 0x05
          LE Limited Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: not assigned (28512)
          Data: 3848f8e6a000
        128-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3
        RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                       [hci1] 5.819728
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Non connectable undirected - ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x03)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: A0:E6:F8:48:EF:78 (Texas Instruments Inc)
        Data length: 31
        Flags: 0x05
          LE Limited Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: not assigned (30816)
          Data: ef48f8e6a000
        128-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3
        RSSI: -70 dBm (0xba)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                       [hci0] 6.011983
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Non connectable undirected - ADV_NONCONN_IND (0x03)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: A0:E6:F8:48:87:DA (Texas Instruments Inc)
        Data length: 31
        Flags: 0x05
          LE Limited Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: not assigned (55904)
          Data: 8748f8e6a000
        128-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3
        RSSI: -74 dBm (0xb6)
```

Comment: Duplicate. You may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/77340615?noredirect=1

Comment: @LukasIsselbächer actually it is not a duplicate, the task or question is more complex this time. This time it requires parse by hci0\hci1 and so on and give different files having the same other search conditions, so it  branches now by hciX. Also in that thread it was advised to ask this separately.

Comment: You did not ask a question. What is the problem or question? Or are you asking for someone to give you the code?

Comment: @jww kind of question: how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, awk, Python, Perl you can:

1. Separate the text into blocks;
2. Test each block for the the three regex tests you describe;
3. Parse the block;
4. Print to the appropriate file.

The first part is aided by using `sed` to add a `\n` between blocks and then use `awk` to process each block. Here `sed` and `awk` are producing the blocks (2 of them) that are of interest:

```
$ sed 's/^>/\
&/' file | awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
  /UUIDs/ && /32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3/ && /\[hci[01]\]/'
```

Now add `awk` to that to that the blocks into the two files:

```
$ sed 's/^>/\
&/' file | 
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
  /UUIDs/ && /32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3/ && /\[hci[0-9]+\]/ {
      s1=s2=fo=""
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if (match($i,/\[hci[0-9]+/))
                 fn=substr($i,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
            if (match($i,/Address: /))
                 s1=substr($i,RSTART+RLENGTH, 17)
            else if (match($i,/ RSSI:/)) {
                 match($i,/\(0x[^)]+\)/)
                 s2=toupper(substr($i,RSTART+3, RLENGTH-4))  
            }
        }
     fo="file-" fn ".txt"   
     print s1 " " s2 " => " fo
     print s1 " " s2 > fo
}'    

$ cat file-hci0.txt
A0:E6:F8:48:38:6F AB
A0:E6:F8:48:87:DA B6 
$ cat file-hci1.txt
A0:E6:F8:48:32:94 C3
A0:E6:F8:48:EF:78 BA
```

Comment: You got the idea and the output is correct, but this implements only hci0 nd hci1, and what if we have 3 or five or we don't know how much - could you please modify it for multiple hci?

Comment: cool, it worked for me, you are genius, I wish I could this magic.

Answer (score 0):

scriptfile:

```
$1 == ">" {
          cnt++
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                if ( $i ~ /\[.*\]/ ) {
                                 hci[cnt]=substr($i,2,length($i)-2)
                        }
                }
        }
$1 == "Address:" {
           add[cnt]=$2
        }
$0 ~ /32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3/ {
           fnd[cnt]=""
        }
$1 == "RSSI:"   {
           str=substr($4,length($4)-2)
           gsub("\)","",str)
           rssi[cnt]=toupper(str)
        }
END {
           for (i in fnd) {
                        print add[i]" "rssi[i] > "file-"hci[i]".txt"
                }
    }




awk -f scriptfile filename
```

With awk and using scriptfile for the awk code, when we encounter a ">" this signifies the new block of data and so we increment the variable cnt. We then loop through each field on this line and check it against anything starting with [ and ending with ]. This text then has the [ and ] removed with substr and gets added to an array hci indexed with cnt. We then store all the addresses in the array add, and the RSSI text (formatted with substr and gsub ) in rssi. If the mac address is matched, an array fnd is created. All arrays are indexed by cnt. We finally loop through fnd and pull out the other data from the other arrays, printing the output required and redirecting to create the files required.

Comment: What's the point of `system("echo...")` instead of just `print add[i], rssi[i] >  ("file-"hci[cnt]".txt")`?

Comment: Fair point. It's just habit I guess. It's best to file redirection with print but it would need to be >> and not > as there can be multiple entries for each file.

Comment: awk: line 2: function gensub never defined

Comment: What version of ask are you using? It should be a built in function

Comment: awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      1020

Comment: @RamanSailopal you're confusing the semantics of `>` and `>>` in awk vs shell. In awk `>` only means overwrite for the **first** write from the running script.

Comment: Also, you should state the solution is gawk-specific due to `gensub()`.

Comment: @RamanSailopal can this be done wo gensub basing on awk only?

Comment: Please fix the formatting from a single line code. It is just about impossible to read.

Comment: I've changed to put code in a file. I have also changed to use gsub instead of gensub.

Comment: I've also got me access to a copy of mawk and after escaping the ) in the gsub statement, I have verified that it is working as expected.

Comment: 1) If you have to escape `)` in a regexp then your awk is not POSIX compliant as `)` is literal unless following a `(` (just worth knowing, may not have other problems). 2) `print add[i]" "rssi[i] > "file-"hci[i]".txt"` should be `print add[i], rssi[i] > ("file-"hci[i]".txt")` to let the OFS simply do it's job and because any unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior (per POSIX). 3) `$0 ~ /32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3/` can be abbreviated to just `/32f9169f-4feb-4883-ade6-1f0127018db3/`.

Comment: Ruslan, does the solution work or not. I've tested and it looks good to me.